# New to python - Why does only the first line print?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm sure this is super basic to everyone but for some reason I cannot figure out the code below only prints out "Glad to see you back at it again."

I'm new to programming and this is my first attempt to create something small to interact with. Any ideas why the other options in elif and else dont print?

```
def was_read():
    print "Have you read this before?"
    read = raw_input('Yes or No? ')
    if read == 'Yes' or 'yes':
        print 'Glad to see you back at it again.'
    elif read == 'No' or 'no':
        print 'Hope its a good one then!'
    else:
        print "I'm sorry I didn't understand that"
        was_read()
```

Comment: Note that calling `was_read()` inside itself could create a problem for you, as you are stacking function calls deeper each time this happens.  It would be better to wrap the routine in a `while True:` loop and `break` out when you're done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Python may look like English, it isn't English. What you wrote will it be interpreted like:

```
if (read == 'Yes') or ('yes')
```

`'yes'` is truthy, so your `if` statement really acts like:

```
if (read == 'Yes') or True
```

`False or True` and `True or True` are both `True`, so your first `if` statement will always be true.

Be explicit:

```
if read == 'Yes' or read == 'yes'
```

Or just do it the simpler way:

```
if read.lower() == 'yes'
```

Comment: Good explanation (+1). Note that `read.lower() == 'yes'` would result in slightly different behavior; for instance, it would allow `'yEs'` whereas the OP's code would not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and helpful response. Could you explain why this code doesn't need any parentheses?

elif next == "taunt bear" and not bear_moved:
print "The bear has moved from the door. You can go through it now."
bear_moved = True

Comment: @user2093601: Just like `1 + 2 * 3` is `6` because `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, `==` has a higher precedence than `and`.

Comment: @user2093601: By `6` I mean `7` ;)